# Django Return Two Separate __str__ for a Model Form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have a `Task` model that includes tasks and a foreign key to entities:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
```

I have a model that is related to one foreign key in `Task`:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.entity
```

`Task` is placed into a Model Form:

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
            'task',
            'entity'
        ]
```

The Model Form is displayed in the template like this:

```
{{ form.task }}
{{ form.instance.entity }}
```

How would I include the equivalent of `{{ form.instance.type }}`? This would involve somehow including two `__str__` representations in the same model form. I have seen `label_from_instance` used in overriding the model form, but this looks like it's only possible with ModelChoiceFields. In addition, it would render the field as a widget rather than text (like `form.instance`).

Comment: Do you want `{{ form.instance.entity.type }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, `form.instance.entity` is the instance's related `entity`. If you want to display the `type` field, you can simply use:

```
{{ form.instance.entity.type }}
```

To answer the question in your title, each model can only have one `__str__` method. You could define another method or property that returns a string, but there's no need to do this if you just want to display the `type` field.

Comment: wow. i feel like i should go ahead and delete this question...thank you, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Models in Django are just classes. You could also create property for `type` in `Task` class.

```
class Task(models.Mode):
    ... your code ...

    @property
    def entity_type(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.entity.type)
```

Then you'd call `{{ form.instance.entity_type }}` in template.

It's a bit of an overkill in this case, but it might be an option in more complex situations.