# Django Multi value on ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

**my forms.py**

```
class PostsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all()
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = '__all__'
```

On my code above my form look like this:

```
+------------+
|Select    + |
+------------+
|John Doe    |
|Jessica     |
|Jessica     |
|Alex Joe    |
+------------+
```

Hovewer that not what I want since possible multiple name, and I know that value come from `def __str__` on my model.

How to add another **str** so on my field will be:

```
+---------------------+
|Select             + |
+---------------------+
| 012931 - John Doe   |
| 012932 - Jessica    |
| 012933 - Jessica    |
| 012934 - Alex Joe   |
+---------------------+
```

Its contain **id + name** on dropdown, or also other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `User` model on `__str__` you can do as explained in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#str).

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.id, self.user.name)
```

Here is an example of the `self.id`, you can get any value there like `self.name` etc.

Comment: can do with my `forms.py` ?... since on other page, its only need `name`.

Comment: @BudiGunawan refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639263/django-return-two-separate-str-for-a-model-form)

Answer (score 0):

In the `User` class, you should add the methods given below:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.id, self.name)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.id, self.name)
```

**NOTE**: No need for `__unicode__()` if using `Python3.x`.